# Are there any benefits to defining functions within React components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I brought the code below for easy understanding. Note the location of the a function.

There are declarative differences depending on where the a function is in React.
Both are code that works correctly.

Are there any benefits of defining them within React components?

```js
function a(init, sub_name, value) {
  let t2 = cloneDeep(init);
  t2[sub_name] = value;
  return t2;
}

export default function test(props) {
  const [obj, setobj] = useState({
    first: { id: 123, v: 456 },
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <Test
        onUpdateData={(v) => setobj((p) => a(p, "first", v))}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

```js
export default function test(props) {
  const [obj, setobj] = useState({
    first: { id: 123, v: 456 },
  });

  function a(init, sub_name, value) {
    let t2 = cloneDeep(init);
    t2[sub_name] = value;
    return t2;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <Test
        onUpdateData={(v) => setobj((p) => a(p, "first", v))}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

- This is a shortened code that makes it easy to understand the intent of the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first snippet you posted, the `a` function is essentially a private function in that file. It is used by your export but it is not accessible to other scopes.

In the second snippet, you have used a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) to *encapsulate* the `a` function, which is part of the exported function.

Answer (score 2):

This is a design decision that applies to JavaScript (and other languages) in general and not just ReactJS. The primary concern here is to ask if `a()` is used anywhere else or if it is just an implementation detail of `test`. If the later, then it is prefectly fine (and probably even preferred) to declare `a()` as a nested function. If you need to use `a()` in other components, then make it a global function instead.

Comment: Thinking about the benefits you can get from the react life cycle perspective or grammar point of view, I asked the first question. I was missing the most basic one. Obviously, from a clean code perspective, I had to write code according to the purpose, but I was forgetting. Thank you.